# can not save new record to my rails model using mongoid and MongoDB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

Haven't change my code for some time, and it was working fine. But started yesterday, I found I can't save my new record to the mongod db via mongoid.

Background:

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.5'
gem 'mongo', "1.6.2"
gem "mongoid", "2.4.7"
```

mongo server version: 
db version v2.0.5, pdfile version 4.5
MongoDB shell version: 2.0.5

rails models and data size (still in development mode):
3 models (users: 164K, relation: 122M, status:370K)

Problem:  Can't save new users records, as showing here, even it passed the contraints (like I have unique uid, id_str).

```
[2] pry(main)> User.count
=> 164325
[3] pry(main)> u=User.new(uid: 1001, id_str: "1001")
=> #<User _id: 501452f346b0a14fb5000001, _type: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, uid: 1001, id_str: "1001", name: nil, screen_name: nil, location: nil>
[4] pry(main)> u.save
=> true
[5] pry(main)> User.count
=> 164325
[6] pry(main)> u.save!
=> true
[7] pry(main)> User.count
=> 164325
```

Rails log file:

```
MONGODB (0ms) blog_development['$cmd'].find({"count"=>"users", "query"=>{}, "fields"=>nil}).limit(-1)
MONGODB (0ms) blog_development['users'].insert([{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('501452f346b0a14fb5000001'), "uid"=>1001, "id_str"=>"1001", "updated_at"=>2012-07-28 21:00:39 UTC, "created_at"=>2012-07-28 21:00:39 UTC}])
MONGODB (0ms) blog_development['$cmd'].find({"count"=>"users", "query"=>{}, "fields"=>nil}).limit(-1)
MONGODB (0ms) blog_development['$cmd'].find({"count"=>"users", "query"=>{}, "fields"=>nil}).limit(-1)
```

Nothing in the mongodb.log file as the operation is so fast

What could be the reason causing the not-saving issue?

updates:
My db status in mongo shell:

```
"ns" : "blog_development.users",
    "count" : 164325,
    "size" : 159656080,
    "avgObjSize" : 971.5872813022972,
    "storageSize" : 177336320,
    "numExtents" : 14,
    "nindexes" : 3,
    "lastExtentSize" : 36089856,
    "paddingFactor" : 1.0099999999963194,
    "flags" : 1,
    "totalIndexSize" : 22729280,
    "indexSizes" : {
        "_id_" : 9598624,
        "uid_1" : 6091120,
        "screen_name_1" : 7039536
    },
    "ok" : 1
```

os is: 2.6.38-8-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 11 03:31:24 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: What does the DB shell output of `db.users.stats()` look like?  and what O/S are you using?

Comment: updated in the question. seems fine in my db.

Comment: just give a try using create, is it able to save to db. I was not able to get the soln :(

Answer (score 4):

You are using the `save` method which follows "[upsert](http://rdoc.info/github/mongoid/mongoid/Mongoid/Persistence%3asave)" semantics.  If there is an existing document that can be found matching your criteria (`(uid: 1001, id_str: "1001")`), it will be updated instead of inserting a new document.

```
 u=User.new(uid: 1001, id_str: "1001")

 u.save
=> true
```

Since you actually intended to create a new document, you should be using `insert`:

```
u.insert
```

Alternatively, you can also allow a custom `_id` in your class and specify this on creation.  You'll need to [override Mongoid's _id field](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/documents.html#custom_ids) which is readonly by default.

Comment: Actually, there were a duplicated record in my database, find out that later. so you were right. Should distinguish "save" and "insert". Thanks.